# Template function call parameter constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I've a template function, then I pass a simple class to it. The question is why the constructor was called. I research parameter deduction but seem like they're different.

So I've some related question about this case:

1. What is the concept behind this?
2. Can I have any real world example when using this?
3. In the example, only the single parameter Ctr was called. How to call multiple parameters Ctr?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(int v)
    {
        cout << "BAR_1 ctr called" << endl;
        cout << v << endl;
    }
    
    Bar(int v1, int v2)
    {
        cout << "BAR_2 ctr called" << endl;
        cout << v1 << " " << v2 << endl;
    }
};
template<class CT>
void do_foo(const CT& t)
{
    cout << "foo_1 called" << endl;
    return;
}
template<class CT>
void do_foo(const CT& t, const CT& t2)
{
    cout << "foo_2 called" << endl;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    do_foo<Bar>(10);
    do_foo<Bar>(11,12);
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output

```
BAR_1 ctr called                                                                                                                     
10                                                                                                                                   
foo_1 called                                                                                                                         
BAR_1 ctr called                                                                                                                     
12                                                                                                                                   
BAR_1 ctr called                                                                                                                     
11                                                                                                                                   
foo_2 called
```

Comment: please one question per question. I allowed myself to answer something in my answer and ignored the rest ;)

Answer (score 3):

Why the constructor is called is not actually related to the fact that templates are involved. You'd get similar output for:

```
void foo(const Bar& t)
{
    cout << "foo called" << endl;
}

int main() {
    foo(42);
}
```

When you call `foo` with `42` as parameter then the compiler considers one user defined conversion: `foo(const Bar&)` takes a `Bar`, you pass an `int`, there exists a conversion from `int` to `Bar` via the constructor of `Bar`. All fine. `42` is used to create a `Bar` which is passed to `foo`.

---

The effect of templates here is that if you call

```
 do_foo(42);
```

Then template argument deduction will deduce `T` to be `int` and you are calling `do_foo<int>(42);` (ie no `Bar` will be constructed). However, when you explicitly specify the template parameter then no deduction is performed and `do_foo<Bar>` can only take a `Bar` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> In the example, only the single parameter Ctr was called. How to call multiple parameters Ctr?

When you call

```
do_foo<Bar>(11,12);
```

you call `do_foo<Bar>()` with two arguments, so only the two argument version

```
template<class CT>
void do_foo(const CT& t, const CT& t2)
```

matches.

If you want to match the double parameter constructor, surely you can explicitly construct a `Bar` object (and observe that the `CT` template parameter for `do_foo()` can be deduced)

```
 do_foo(Bar{11,12});
```

or you can pass the two integers in a single object using brackets (but you have to explicit again the template parameter for `do_foo()`

```
 do_foo<Bar>({11,12});
```